# What does this command mean: `echo $line | awk -F "\t" '{print $1;}'`?

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

I'm new to this, and I was wondering specifically what `awk -F "\t"` means.

Comment: Read `man awk`. Learn about `-F fs
--field-separator fs
Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).`

Comment: Although GNU awk (gawk) is not the only awk, its online manual is quite useful for stuff like this - see in particular [Specifying How Fields Are Separated](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators) and [Setting FS from the Command Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Command-Line-Field-Separator)

Answer (score 0):

Very likely this is inside a script.
the input variable $line is being checked with the awk command.  The separator is the tab character \t.

Because this is being executed in a script the action is to parse and return ( with the '{ print $1 }' script being passed to awk ) the value in $line up to but not including the first tab character.

The advice given by @waltinator is good, but so many distracting details in the manual can make it hard to understand.

Instead, you can learn about the cool stuff awk can do with skimming https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one

Comment: Note that if it's inside a *bash* (or really any common shell other than zsh) script, the expansion of the `line` variable should be quoted, as `"$line"` otherwise it will be subject to word splitting which (with the default IFS value) will result in any whitespace sequences (including tabs) being replaced with single space characters - making the attempt to split on tabs with awk moot